# How to insert value into DB2 from SQL Server using openquery which are not already inserted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2-400, openquery

Is there any option to use not exists in `openquery` from SQL Server and prevent insert of values which already exist in DB2, from table.

I want to insert data from a table located in SQL Server into a table located in an IBM DB2 server, but I want to check if the value already exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me actually,

```
if not exists (select * from openquery(puskarkc, 'select * from puskarlib.castatus'))
begin
insert openquery (puskarkc, 'select * from puskarlib.castatus') 
select * from castatus
end
```